# Layout-sw400dp not called. Multiple screen support

Tags: android, android-layout

I have multiple layouts to support different screen sizes:

`layout-sw320dp (smallest phones, 4.0" and smaller)`

`layout-sw360dp (approximately 4.7-5")`

`layout-sw400dp (most phones right now, 5-6")`

Note: This values are from `Design` tab in `Layout Editor` from Android Studio.
(Example for `layout-sw320dp`)

[image]

First layout (`layout-sw320dp`) for small screen sizes was designed in `Android Emulator` on `Nexus S`

Second layout (`layout-sw360dp`) was designed on a real device `Samsung Galaxy A3 2017 - 4.7''`

Both of them works! Every layout is called according to phone screen size: `layout-sw320dp` on `Nexus S` which is `4.0'` and `layout-sw360dp` on my phone which is `4.7"`.

My problem arises with `layout-sw400dp` which should be called on devices with `5"` and bigger. For this layout I have another real phone `Samsung Galaxy S7 edge - 5.5"` but on this phone, the app is calling `layout-sw360dp` instead of `layout-sw400dp`. This occurs only on my real phone. In `Android Emulator` on `Pixel XL` (which has the exact same specs of screen as `S7 edge` - `5.5"` and the same resolution) the app call the right layout.

**Update:** Example for `layout-sw400dp` 
[image]

My questions are: Why is this happening? How can I solve this that phones with `5"` and bigger call other layout than `layout-sw360dp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung S7 Edge is a 5.5 inch phone and it falls under `sw360dp` category

That means, everyting is working as it should be

link https://material.io/tools/devices/

*The point is,* DP doesn't depend solely on screen side, it depends of the sreen size and how many pixel the display actually has.

Comment: `Pixel XL` is also 5.5 inch and it's working with `sw400dp`.

Comment: The point is, DP doesn't depend solely on screen side, it depends of the sreen side and how many pixel the display actually has.

Comment: Yes, both phones have the same resolution and 5.5'' but their DP is different `411 x 731` for Pixel and `360 x 640` for S7 and thet's why... Anyway good site I wasn't aware of it. Thanks!

Comment: my pleasure. you might also take a look at this article https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: I'll look! 
Olso I found this libray, I will give it a try!
https://github.com/intuit/sdp